# How to query batch by batch from ElasticSearch in nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get data from ElasticSearch with my node application. In my index, there are 1 million records, thus I cannot be sent to another services with the whole records. That's why I want to get 10,000 records per request, as per example:

```
const getCodesFromElasticSearch = async (batch) => {
  let startingCount = 0;
  if (batch > 1) {
    startingCount = (batch * 1000);
  } else if (batch === 1) {
    startingCount = 0;
  }
  return await esClient.search({
    index: `myIndex`,
    type: 'codes',
    _source: ['column1', 'column2', 'column3'],
    body: {
      from: startingCount,
      size: 1000,
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
              ....
          ],
          filter: {
              ....
          }
        }
      },
      sort: {
        sequence: {
          order: "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(data => data.hits.hits.map(esObject => esObject._source));
}
```

It's still working when `batch=1`. But when goes to `batch=2`, that got problem that `from` should not be larger than `10,000` as per its documentation. And I don't want to change `max_records` as well. Please let me know any alternate way to get `10,000` by `10,000`.

Answer (score 1):

The **scroll API** can be used to retrieve large numbers of results (or even all results) from a single search request, in much the same way as you would use the cursor on a traditional database.

So you can use `scroll` API to get your whole 1M dataset below-something like below without using **from** because elasticsearch normal search has a limit of 10k record in max request so when you try to use from with greater value then it'll return error, that's why scrolling is good solutions for this kind of scenarios.

```
let allRecords = [];

// first we do a search, and specify a scroll timeout
var { _scroll_id, hits } = await esclient.search({
index: 'myIndex',
type: 'codes',
scroll: '30s',
body: {
    query: {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    _source: ["column1", "column2", "column3"]
  }
})

while(hits && hits.hits.length) {
// Append all new hits
allRecords.push(...hits.hits)

console.log(`${allRecords.length} of ${hits.total}`)

var { _scroll_id, hits } = await esclient.scroll({
    scrollId: _scroll_id,
    scroll: '30s'
 })
}

console.log(`Complete: ${allRecords.length} records retrieved`)
```

You can also add your `query` and `sort` with this existing code snippets.

**As per comment:**

**Step 1.** Do normal `esclient.search` and get the `hits` and `_scroll_id`. Here you need to send the `hits` data to your other service and keep the `_scroll_id` for a future batch of data calling.

**Step 2** Use the `_scroll_id` from the first batch and use a while loop until you get all your 1M record with `esclient.scroll`. Here you need to keep in mind that you don't need to wait for all of your 1M data, within the while loop when you get response back just send it to your service batch by batch.

**See Scroll API**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/scroll_examples.html

**See Search After **: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search-request-search-after.html

Comment: I know that solution already. Problem is I don't want to get the whole records inside my index because of performance issue will be happening at receiver side, that's why I want to send batch by batch.

Comment: @PPShein I am little bit confused by your comment, using scroll API you'll get data by scroll limit, so you can send that dataset to your other service, then next scrolled dataset to your server and so on.

Comment: as I mentioned in my question as well, I don't want to return over 1 million records in single request because of receiver's performance. That's why I want to response 10,000 records per single request. But in `from`, that cannot be allowed to put 10,000 value.

Comment: @PPShein I've updated my answer with some steps, please have a look and let me know is that make sense, **Maybe I'm wrong** but it seems your not very much familiar with scroll api's work approach. Correct me if I'm wrong :)